Solving a homogeneous linear recursion relation with boundary condition at end points
Model: a fair coin is tossed repeatedly and the gambler gets $+1$ for head, and $-1$ for tail. Continue until he is broke or achieves $ \$a$. Let
$$p_x = \Pr(\text{goes broke}| \text{starts with \$}x)$$
By law of total probability, we have the recurrence relation $p_x
            = \frac{1}{2}p_{x+2}+\frac{1}{2}p_{x-2}$ with boundary condition $p_0=1, p_a=0$.
I wonder how to find $p_x$ from this recurrence equation. I know one way maybe to derive from there that
$$p_x-p_{x-1}=\cdots =p_1-p_0.$$
But I am still not using both conditions $p_0=1, p_a=0$.

If you know that
$$p_x-p_{x-1}=\cdots =p_1-p_0$$
and $p_0=1, p_a=0$, then these uniquely specify the $p_x$'s. Notice that
$$-1 = p_a-p_0 = \sum_{x=1}^a(p_x-p_{x-1}) = a(p_1-p_0),$$
so $p_1=1-\frac1a$, and likewise $p_x=1-\frac xa$ for $x\in \{ 0,1,\ldots,a \}$.

Okay unique for sure. But how do you solve the equation for it. I prefer a solution from scratch not a guessed answer for verification

@taylor I've edited my answer with an explicit solution.
